# Electron: How to execute bundled file?

Tags: javascript, electron, filesystems, browserify, fs

**TL;DR:** I have a bundled JS file `bundle.js` created with Browserify. I want to load this file and attach the contents to a `BrowserView` in Electron using `executeJavaScript`. How can I do this?

The package I need to include is Web3.js. I bundled Web3 with Browserify by running:

```
browserify packages/web3/src/index.js -o web3-bundle.js
```

Here are the two most promising approaches to include the package into the `BrowserView`, which both unfortunately didn't work.

1. Using `require`.

I tried using `require` to import the file.

```
const Web3 = require('web3-bundle.js');

view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
  ${Web3};
  console.log(Web3);
`);
```

2. Using `fs`:

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'web3-bundle.js'), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('data', data)
view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
  ${data};
  console.log(Web3);
`)
});
```

How can you attach a bundled file into a `BrowserView` in Electron?

Answer (score 0):

You can preload a script to a `BrowserView`

```
const view = new BrowserView( { webPreferences: { preload : 'absloute/path/to/web3-bundle.js' } } )
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, because for security reasons, I have to set `contextIsolation` to `true`, which is why I also have to use `executeJavaScript` to load it somehow.